# Oracle Database BLOB to InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, blob, inputstream

I made a Java function that takes an `InputStream` as an input.  I have a `oracle.sql.BLOB` instance to pass to that function. How can I convert it to a `InputStream`?

Do I need to re-write my function using a BLOB parameter, instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your Java parameter of type `oracle.sql.BLOB` as per the ["Mapping Datatypes" documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b12021/pub.htm#1005611). Then, you call `getBinaryStream()` on that `BLOB` object to obtain your `InputStream`.

Comment: and then? how do I convert it to InputStream?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't really said how you're fetching data from the database, but you can use [`ResultSet.getBinaryStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28int%29) to get an `InputStream`, or call `getBlob()` to get a `Blob`, and then `getBinaryStream()` on the `Blob` to get a stream.

Comment: we fatch it with PL/SQL so nothing special here, where there is a PL/SQL function that call the java function and return the results

Comment: @Data-Base: I meant which client technology you were using - an ORM such as Hibernate, direct JDBC, which driver etc.

Comment: not sure what do you mean but none! we just query the database from the PL/SQL and send the variable to the function the function take the variable convert the data and return a text

the Java is compiled as class inside the Oracle Database

Comment: @Data-Base: Ah - that's a different matter then. It's relatively rare to come across Java code running in the database... I wish you'd said that to start with, as I've no idea how that works. Basically look for `Blob`-related calls in whatever API you've got...