# Spring: Download data while streamly reading from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have to create a webpage using Spring to download data to csv and pdf from a database table. Because of the large amount of data, if I read it to the webpage first it will bring out-of-memory. I am wondering if there is any way that Spring can download the data streamly while reading from database?

Comment: Are you using something like hibernate ? It looks like to me that the problem does not come from Spring, but more from your database framework.

Comment: Anyway, using Spring or not, using Hibernate or not, you always can use ResultSet to get tthe Blob or the BinaryStream of your data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049974/oracle-database-blob-to-inputstream-in-java

Comment: Also you don't want to display it "in a web page," instead you want to write the stream of data to the output stream without collecting all of it on the server (likely as an attachment).

Comment: @ChrisThompson how about create and saving the file to the server first and then return a FileSystemResource in the controller?